# c# dependency injection with interfaces and hiding internal

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection

I am trying to refactor some classes in a project to make them testable using interfaces and dependency injection. But I struggle with the following:

```
public interface IInterfaceA 
{
   void SomePublicMethod();
}

public class ConcreteObject : IInterfaceA
{
   public void SomePublicMethod() { ... }
   public void SomeOhterMethod() { ... }
   public void YetAnotherMethod() { ... }
}

public class AnotherConcreteObject 
{
    private IInterfaceA _myDependency;
    public AnotherConcreteObject( IInterfaceA myDependency )
    {
       _myDependency=myDependency;
    }
}
```

So far everything is fine, pretty standard code. AnotherConcreteObject needs to call SomeOtherMethod, but I don't want other classes (e.g. in a different assembly) to be able to call SomeOtherMethod. So externally SomePublicMethod should be visible, but SomeOtherMethod should not be. Only instances of AnotherConcreteObject should be able to call SomeOtherMethod. SomeOtherMethod will e.g. set a internal property which is used later by YetAnotherMethod to determine what should happen. The internal property is set to a default value in all other cases e.g. when YetAnotherMethod is called from any other class than AnotherConcretObject.

When not using interfaces, this is possible because AnotherConcreteObject is in the same assembly as ConcreteObject so it has access to internal properties and methods. Classes in a different assembly can not set this property or call the method because they don't have access to internal properties and methods.

Comment: If `AnotherConcreteObject` needs to call something which isn't in the public interface, then it should depend on `ConcreteObject` rather than the interface - or possibly another interface which exposes `SomeOtherMethod`.

Comment: But if AnotherConcreteObject depends on Concrete object directly, doesn't this make AnotherConcreteObject more difficult (or impossible) to test? I want AnotherConcreteObject to be testable using mocking

Comment: Are you having issues testing the AnotherConcreteObject  because of instances of AnotherConcreteObject calls SomeOtherMethod which is sets an internal property?

Comment: I have just started to look at how to model the interface(s) so I can make my classes more testable, so I'm not yet writing any tests. I followed a course on using a mocking framework, and learned the importance of interfaces. So now I'm looking for a way to model my interfaces in this scenario.

Comment: That's why I suggested having another interface which exposed `SomeOtherMethod`. It may be an interface which extends `IInterfaceA` for example.

Comment: Ok, I could extend IInterfaceA, but then how does injection works?
suppose IInteraceB extends from IInterfaceA, should I make IInterfaceB internal, I think I tried that, and then got compiler issues.
Also the instance implementing the interfaces should remain the same instance (e.g. when ConcreteObject has a lifecycle singleton for a http request)

Comment: Suppose I refactor ConcreteObject to have an additionally dependency on internal interface IInterfaceB. I can make an internal constructor for ConcreteObject that accepts this dependency. Suppose a single ConcreteObject is created every http request. Class A from a different assembly asks for the instance of ConcreteObject...  Class B in the same assembly of ConcreteObject also asks for instance of ConcreteObject. Both A and B should get same instance. Since A asked for the object first, the dependency cannot be injected. What is the best way to inject this dependency when B asks for it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possible solutions, depending on what exactly you are doing:

1 if `SomePublicMethod` is public, but `SomeOtherMethod` is internal, then don't put them in the same class and they likely do very different things and so the separation of concerns principle comes in to play.
2 If `ConcreteObject` doesn't have state and doesn't cause side effects, or if you aren't going to run tests against it in parallel, ie has unit behaviour, then it may not need mocking, so access it directly.

Comment: SomeOtherMethod and SomePublicMethod should be in the same class, because SometOtherMethod affects the behaviour of the class in other parts.

Comment: @rekna if the two methods must be in the same class, then I'd question why one is internal and the other public. It is likely an indication that the class is doing too much.

Comment: Suppose the two method configure/setup the class, while the third method excutes the main functionality of the class. Those methods affect the control flow of this main functionality.